# Viewing assembly code of functions in emacs

Tags: gcc, emacs, ide, clang

I'm wondering if there's a package for emacs that would allow me to see the generated assembly code quickly of a function? This should also work with compiler optimizations enabled. What I'd like is to be able to with one command open a new buffer which would contain the assembly code of the current function.

Xcode on OS X does this very nicely, but I'd like to switch back to Linux and emacs on my dev workstation and this is a feature I've learned to like a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`disaster.el`](https://github.com/jart/disaster):

> [image: Disaster screenshot]
>
> Disaster lets you press `C-c d` to see the compiled assembly code for the C/C++ file you're currently editing. It even jumps to and highlights the line of assembly corresponding to the line beneath your cursor.
>
> It works by creating a `.o` file using make (if you have a Makefile) or the default system compiler. It then runs that file through objdump to generate the human-readable assembly.

`disaster.el` is [available in MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/disaster).

Comment: Thanks, can I specify the path/directory where Makefile exists? I work in a tree that has multiple build targets each in a directory.

Comment: @SFbay007, I don't think so. It looks like [`disaster.el` follows a predefined search path looking for `Makefile`s and then falls back to `cc` or `c++`](https://github.com/jart/disaster#function-documentation).